# Install Python packages from tar.gz or .whl in GCP Composer

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-composer

I need to install some packages in a GCP Composer environment directly from a tar.gz or .whl file. In a normal environment I can just use `pip install https://url.to.package/package.whl` but Composer seems to not allow this.

Checking the documentation (https://cloud.google.com/composer/docs/how-to/using/installing-python-dependencies) it seems that you can install packages from a "public repository" but it need to be a proper git repository. What if my .tar.gz or .whl is on a random web server? Do anyone have a solution?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Um, it's in the documentation you literally linked, see [Install from a repository with a public IP address](https://cloud.google.com/composer/docs/how-to/using/installing-python-dependencies#install-public-repo) - and provided that `https://url.to.package/` provides a public listing to the `.whl` file then the configuration would work - if running `pip install --extra-index-url=https://url.to.package/ package` will install your package, configure `extra-index-url` as documented will make it work. The public listing can be a page that [looks like this](https://pypi.org/simple/example-package/)

Comment: As I said that is not working in my case since I don't have a page like this. More specifically, the .whl file is on a Github release with a url like that: https://github.com/.../releases/download/<PACKAGE>.whl

Comment: The `.whl`s being on Github is an important detail to omit from the question. You also left out if you are the author of those `.whl` files but "my .tar.gz or .whl" seriously implies that they are, so if they are not yours you should also include that. If they are yours, you could use [github pages](https://pages.github.com/) to create a simple page like that to link to your `.whl` files.

Comment: Otherwise, remember you are using a cloud hosting service after all, the whole point of this is being able to put data of all kinds there. Looking further _on the same page you have linked_ see [Install from an Artifact Registry repository](https://cloud.google.com/composer/docs/how-to/using/installing-python-dependencies#install-ar-repo), note how GCP will give you space for you to store your own artifacts. Keep reading all the links there to set this up yourself.

Comment: Alternatively you can just simply put the links to the `.whl` directly into [`find-links`](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/cli/pip_install/#cmdoption-f) part in the [`pip.conf` install section](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/topics/configuration/#repeatable-options).

Comment: Anyway if any of these work let me know, so maybe I can turn all those comments into an actual answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can install custom packages in a Cloud Composer environment by following this [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/composer/docs/how-to/using/installing-python-dependencies#install-public-repo). As emphasized, it is important to properly configure packages so that the default pip tool can install it. The basic steps are:
1. Create a pip.conf file
2. Upload this pip.conf file to the /config/pip/ folder in your environment's bucket
3. Install packages using one of the available methods.